# Is &amp;amp; valid

Tags: xml

We get a lot of xml data from various sources. The utf is 8.

We notice that some have what appears to be double encoding of the `&`.  `&amp;&amp;` within the tag for `A & B`
comes in as `A &amp;amp; B`. (Corrected from original posting was &&)

This causes some grief as most of the XML components do not like it.

Is it valid?  What is the best way of remove these?  We use VB.Net 2008

Comment: That's not a double-encoding of `&`. That would be `&amp;amp;` - you wouldn't have a second `&` still appearing. If you double-**decode** `&amp;&amp;` then yes, you'll have a problem, because the second decode will attempt to process `&&` which isn't valid.

Comment: Your title and your question contradict each other. Which is it?

Comment: You're correct what comes in is &amp;amp;  for just &.  So this is invalid because what the sender did was to double encode the &.
&=?&amp;=>&amp;amp;

So currently we are just doing a replace("&amp;amp;", "&amp;")

The program does not read thru each field but just dumps the XML to be XSLT transformed.

So do you see any other solution or potential problems???

Comment: Tim, The title is correct.  I do not see a contraction.  Please explain.

Comment: Some badly-configured (or maybe faulty) wysiwyg editors will convert "&" to "&amp;" and then next time around convert the "&amp;" to "&amp;amp;" and next time again to "&amp;amp;amp;" etc. If it helps, I think it is likely that this is what is causing the original problem.

Answer (score 12):

`&amp;amp;` is "valid", though whether you want to use it is another question.

If you're writing a document in XML, then `&amp;` will be used to represent an ampersand. If your XML document is describing content that itself is encoded in a similar way -- e.g. HTML -- then that content could logically include an `&amp;` itself. This could lead to a `&amp;amp;` in the XML.

For example, let's say you have XML describing a set of users, including a "signature" field that supports HTML:

```
<users>
 <user username="jsmith" ...>
  ...
  <signature type="text/html">
   John Smith's Heating And Plumbing
  </signature>
</users>
```

If John Smith wanted to use a `&` instead of `And` in his signature, it would be...

```
  <signature type="text/html">
   John Smith's Heating &amp; Plumbing
  </signature>
```

...where the `&` is encoded as `&amp;` to keep the XML parser happy.

Think of the situation in which the signature is being included in an HTML email. The XML parser will decode `&amp` into `&`. If the signature is being dumped directly into the email, this will result in a "&" entity appearing unescaped in the message's source.

However, if the XML had included `&amp;amp;`, upon XML parsing it would become `&amp;`. Then it would be included in the email as properly-escaped HTML.

A more readable way of accomplishing the same escaping might be this...

```
  <signature type="text/html">
   <![CDATA[John Smith's Heating &amp; Plumbing]]>
  </signature>
```

The above presumes that the signature is to include HTML-encoded entities, which are further encoded into the XML documented. This is the source of the apparent double-encoding. If, for example, the signature should only include plain text, then there would only be a single encoding -- `&` from the plain-text into `&amp;` for the XML document. Thus both `&amp;amp;` and `&amp;` are "valid" from an XML perspective, and in practice it will depend on the specification for the data to be encoded into the XML document.

(A third option when writing the XML schema would be to use XML namespacing to permit contained HTML to be included without double-encoding; this would have the added benefit of permitting it to be validated, but in practice applying strict XML-style validation to HTML content is a headache. See e.g. the failed attempt to promote and standardize on XHTML.)

Comment: We do not create this.  We get it from external systems. Or if we are getting &amp;amp; in A&B which is A&amp;B not A&B then I would guess it is invalid since the real results should just be A&B.

Comment: What I'm explaining above is how ``&amp;amp;`` might legitimately arise. If your upstream data provider is generating an XML file in which they're encoding HTML content, as above, then ``&amp;amp;`` is legit. If your upstream data source is shipping XML-encoded HTML and you're expecting plain text, then the difference in expectations is the problem. My suspicion is that you need to clarify whether that XML element should contain HTML (& would be ``&amp;amp;``) or plaintext (& would be ``&amp;``).

Comment: We are reading the XML and converting it to plain text for another process.  We do not want any escaping in the text we are converting. The problem is that it is parsing it leaving a &amp; where we want just an & for the plain text.  The code now does NOT do double parsing and I do not think that it should.

Comment: Then the problem is that your upstream provider is giving you (most probably) HTML encoded in XML, and you're expecting plain text encoded in XML. You'll probably see similar problems with ``>`` and ``<`` symbols being encoded as ``&amp;gt;`` and ``&amp;lt;``, respectively. Both encodings are technically valid, but you need to determine which of you is following the data specification.

Comment: I did not think that we would have to do double parsing.  That just sounds wrong.  I am not expecting plain text but XML.  So then every XML document we need requires double parsing?

Comment: "So then every XML document we need requires double parsing?" -- yes, if you're exchanging XML that encodes HTML tags in its contents. The first parsing is done by the XML parser (``&amp;amp;`` to ``&amp;``, the second by the web browser (``&amp;`` to ``&``). Again, the question is whether that element in your XML is supposed to contain text/plain (what you seem to expect) or text/html (what you're probably getting from upstream).

Comment: No,  only reading data.  No web anything involved after we get the data.  This usually just occurs with company names such as A&B becoming A&amp;&amp;B.  We parse and left with A&amp;B and that goes into a plain file.  And that is incorrect as far as I can see. 

It is NOT our xml but what we get i.e. API query for customer name, etc.

Comment: @QuickBooksDev, I've explained it to the best of my ability but I think we're going around in circles. Long story short: you need to clarify with your data source whether the data in that element is supposed to contain HTML encoded into XML, or plain text encoded into XML. That will clarify whether you should expect a ``&`` to appear in your XML as ``&amp;amp;`` or ``&amp;``. At the purely XML level, both are valid data.

Comment: It is NOT for html.  Just a simple data query like Customer Name. 

Then everything has to be double parsed since your are saying that
&amp;amp; is valid.

Comment: OK, in that case you can tell the upstream provider that they're sending HTML-encoded entities into what's supposed to be a plain-text XML element. If they're not willing to correct it or disagree with you about the specification, then you're forced to double-decode, unfortunately.

(In your comment above you mention ``&amp;&amp;`` rather than ``&amp;amp;`` as you've described everywhere else -- that's a totally different situation; I'm guessing it's a typo?)